# Beautiful Soup Get Data Bind Element

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2">
                    <span class="small text-muted">Court</span>
                </div><div class="col-xs-11 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-0">
                    <span class="small" data-bind="html: model.Court">Wayne Township</span>



from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

court = response_soup.find('span', {'class': 'Model.court'}).text
```

The result is NONE
I am trying to get Wayne Township
Wayne Township will not always be the result.
Any assistance would be most appreciated.

Comment: In that element, the class is "small".  Why are you looking for class="Model.court"?

Comment: I assume `{'data-bind': 'Model.court'}` would work.

Comment: court = response_soup.find('span', {'data-bind': 'Model.court'}) still gets result of  "none" court = response_soup.find({'data-bind': 'Model.court'}) still gets result of NONE

Comment: Oops, I meant to say `{'data-bind': 'html: model.court'} ` I forgot the "html:"

Comment: Result is still "none'

Comment: capital c in `model.Court`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to add selenium The correct syntax is court=browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"//span[@data-bind='html: model.Court']")